# Simplified analysis of complex circuits

Tags: circuit-analysis

This is a question in very general sense. When we got to analyze very complex schematics, is there any way by which it can be made simpler. Like do we have any key steps to analyze it with.

Comment: This question is far too broad to be answered. Do you have an example circuit in mind?

Comment: Ok. For example we can start with opamp-LM741 internal circuitry.

Comment: Ignore everything inside the op-amp and get your head around what an op-amp does on the outside. Are you at this stage yet?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a simple general rule that lets you break down any complex circuit into small modules to simplify understanding.

The first steps I usually take is to understand what is the circuit's purpose and to find its "interfaces" (power supply, input and output signals). Then I try to examine the "path of the signal" through the circuit, so I can focus on the "important parts".

You need to understand which parts and devices are fundamental for the functionality and which are just "accessory parts" (e.g. for noise suppression, ESD protection).

If you manage to proceed these steps, you usually get a good understanding of the circuit.

In general, like in software development, I think a circuit designer should always provide good documentation in the schematics by simply adding helpful notes to the different parts of the circuit. Unfortunately, often there is not a single note in schematics. Here, hardware designers could learn a lot by their software colleagues...

Comment: Your last sentence I strongly disagree with. A circuit diagram should fully define the functionality and likely performance of a circuit and notes may be useful but I'm yet to see a piece of code (and its documentation) that gets anywhere near defining how it works in the entirety that a basic circuit diagram does.

Comment: My personal experience is that, when I have to analyze and understand circuits from former colleagues, I often end up spending a lot of time of analyzing the different "sub-modules" of the circuit - if the designer would have spend a minute to write some notes, it would save me a lot of time.
Of course the circuit is "fully defined" without notes, but is it easy to understand? A software will run without any comments, too, but good design includes good documentation.

Comment: You haven't swayed me one iota - there is nothing equivalent to a circuit diagram in code and the more experienced circuit-readers will usually have no problem getting to grips within a few minutes with an "alien" circuit.

Comment: I'm not willing to start some kind of "comment war" here - I can just state that you haven't swayed me one iota, too.
Go on with your way of doing circuit diagrams, I don't care. I will go on with mine. Perhaps it would be more helpful to the original poster if you tell him your way to analyze a circuit.